# Lost your password placement working on the login page but not working on the checkout page

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am using Woocommerce. I have issues with the checkout page.

What I did, I just change the placement of the Lost your password in the login page`(my-account->form-login.php)`. I mean I added the Lost your password above the Login button.

Now, I am getting the correct changes on the login page. (https://example.com/my-account/)

but when I am on the checkout page and click on the login then I am getting the old code. The Lost your password still showing below the Login button.

**Login page**

[image]

**Checkout page**

[image]

Do I need to change anything more on this?

```html
<form class="woocommerce-form woocommerce-form-login login" method="post">

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_login_form_start' ); ?>

<p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
  <label for="username"><?php esc_html_e( 'Username or email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
  <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="username" id="username" autocomplete="username" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['username'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['username'] ) ) : ''; ?>" /><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
</p>
<p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
  <label for="password"><?php esc_html_e( 'Password', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
  <input class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" type="password" name="password" id="password" autocomplete="current-password" />
</p>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_login_form' ); ?>

<p class="form-row">
  <label class="woocommerce-form__label woocommerce-form__label-for-checkbox woocommerce-form-login__rememberme">
    <input class="woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox" name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever" /> <span><?php esc_html_e( 'Remember me', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span>
  </label>
</p>

<p class="woocommerce-LostPassword lost_password">
  <a href="<?php echo esc_url( wp_lostpassword_url() ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Lost your password?', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
</p>

<?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-login', 'woocommerce-login-nonce' ); ?>
<button type="submit" class="woocommerce-button button woocommerce-form-login__submit" name="login" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Log in', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Log in', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_login_form_end' ); ?>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The checkout login form is taken from global, which is found at:

`/woocommerce/templates/global/form-login.php`

Comment: Yes, It's working. In the child theme, I have /woocommerce/global/form-login.php